# Do I have to use the article "a" with the names of illnesses that contain the word "disorder"?

Tags: articles, indefinite-article

Could you tell me if I have to use the article *a* with the names of illnesses that contain the word *disorder*?

For example, is it *people with dissociative personality disorder* or *people with **a** dissociative personality disorder*?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use *a* if *dissociative personality disorder* is a particular disease, that is, if there aren't various kinds of it.

However, if you are speaking of various disorders that people may have, you may wish to use *a* to point to that particular disorder out of several under discussion.

Answer (score -1):

Short answer: Yes. It's "a such-and-such disorder".

The rules for use of an article with a disease are murky.

Some diseases take no article: "Al has diabetes. Betty has sleep apnia."

Some take "the": "Carl has the flue. Diane has the measles."

Some take "a": "Ed has a heart murmur. Francine has a virus."

Maybe there's a general rule based on the type of disease. I don't know. You probably just have to learn them one by one.

Comment: "A flea and a fly in a flue." The disease is "flu." The breathing thing is "apnea."

Comment: @Dan, where I live it's _apnoea_. Also, where I live, Jay, we don't really use 'the' before any diseases, certainly not 'the flu' or 'the measles'. It's a long while since we used an initial apostrophe with **'flu** (because it's short for _influenza_)

Comment: @Dan "Flue" above was a typo. I really do know how to spell it. "Apnea" I just didn't know how to spell.

Comment: @MichaelWokeHarvey Where do you live? "Apnoea" looks like a UK spelling to me but could be many places. So there do they say, "Bob has flu"? I don't recall ever seeing that. But okay, I guess my post is specific to the US. Oh, yes, I'm aware that "flu" is short for "influenza" but I don't recall ever seeing it with an apostrophe. Again, maybe a regionalism.

Comment: @Jay - yes, UK, but apnoea is common in other parts of the British English zone, Australia, New Zealand, Ireland, South Africa, etc. LIkewise diarrhoea, haemorrhage, anaesthetic, etc. Yes we/they say 'Bob has flu'. Apostrophe - flu has been gone since before WW2.